# Why can't I get the URI of profile pic from a contact number?

Tags: android, imageview, uri, photo, contacts

I have a custom incoming call screen that can current show the name and phone number of an incoming call. If the contact has a profile pic set (on your own phone), that image should display in the ImageView I've created. Any number that not on the phone will show the Android icon.

After testing the code, no matter if the phone number is stored on the phone (emulator) or not, I get the Android icon. Here is the code to retrieve the contact photo of the caller if one is available:

```
public Uri getPhotoUri(long contactId) { //contactId takes the phone number.

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    try {
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver
            .query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                    + "="
                    + contactId
                    + " AND "

                    + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                    + "='"
                    + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                    + "'", null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
        if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return null; // no photo
        }
        } else {
        return null; // error in cursor process
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
    return Uri.withAppendedPath(person,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
  }
```

This method calls the above method, and assigns the picture to the ImageView. The problem is that the else statement is always executed:

**IncomingCallListener.getId(getID))); is the actual phone number used to get the corresponding profile picture.**

```
public void showContactPhoto(){

    Uri u = getPhotoUri(IncomingCallListener.getId(getID()));
    if (u != null) {    
        qcbContactPic.setImageURI(u);
        Log.d("PHOTO", "ID launched");
    } else {
        qcbContactPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Log.d("PHOTO", "Default launched");
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why "u" is remaining null?

**NOTE: The contact picture is stored in the media gallery.**

Comment: Have you added the image to the contact in Emulator?

Comment: what's your target SDK level? ICS or gingerbread? In ICS (lvl 14) you have the `PHOTO_FILE_ID` that can be used to find the high-resolution image, otherwise you're pretty much stuck with the thumbnail stored in `PHOTO`.

Comment: @blackcrow getting the name and number works fine, but the problem is that this code is registering that "u" is null, thus only displaying "ic_launcher" which is suppose to be for contacts that aren't stored, or don't have a profile image already set to a contact.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, longId);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts
                    .openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
            if (input == null) {
                return null;
            } else
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Use setImageBitmap() method of ImageView.

Comment: I can assure you, this is working code. Try to single out where exactly the problem is.

Comment: This is suppose to set the image: qcbContactPic.setImageBitmap(getShowCPhoto(IncomingCallListener.getId(getID())));

Comment: could it be that the picture Im using is a jpeg instead of a bitmap?

Comment: I used the setImageBitmap() in my comment above. qcbContactPic is my ImageView. From there, no image showed up.